# Strange ADC behavior - AVR32DA32

Tags: microcontroller, analog, adc, error

I'm measuring the power supply voltage through a voltage divider against a 2.5V voltage reference on a 12 bit ADC. Hopefully it's pretty clear the error I'm experiencing by looking at the table and graph I attached. 11V and 11.5V as well as 13.5V and 14V read out almost or exactly the same every time. I've tested it on different micros with the same result.

What might be the cause of this? And is there a solution?

ADC initialization code is here. I'm using an Atmel ICE to read the result register.

```
void systemConfigADC()
{
    VREF.ADC0REF |= VREF_REFSEL_2V500_gc;               //ADC0 reference as 2.5V;   
    ADC0.CTRLA |= ADC_RESSEL_12BIT_gc                   //12 bit conversions.
                | ADC_FREERUN_bm;                       //Enable freerunning mode.
    ADC0.CTRLC |= ADC_PRESC_DIV2_gc;                    //ADC clock equals system clock div 2.
    ADC0.SAMPCTRL = 20;                                 //Set sample length to 20 ADC cycles.
    ADC0.CTRLE = ADC_WINCM_BELOW_gc;                    //Compare mode set to below.
    ADC0.MUXPOS = ADC_MUXPOS_AIN21_gc;                  //Battery voltage divider is on PF5 which is AIN21.
    ADC0.MUXNEG = ADC_MUXNEG_GND_gc;                    //Negative input to ground.
    //ADC0.INTCTRL = ADC_WCMP_bm;                       //Enable window comparator interrupt.
    ADC0.WINLT = ADC_LOW_VOLTAGE;                       //Low threshold is 11V.
    ADC0.DBGCTRL = ADC_DBGRUN_bm;                       //Run while debuggin.
    ADC0.CTRLA |= ADC_ENABLE_bm;                        //Enable ADC.
    ADC0.COMMAND = ADC_STCONV_bm;                       //Start converting.
}
```

[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB]
[image: Data Table]
[image: Graph]

Comment: Please show a schematic, PCB layout, and sample code.

Comment: How do you know your supply voltage?

Comment: @TimWilliams Updated post with all of those. I'm using a debugger to read the ADC result register.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm using a benchtop power supply.

Comment: @thebusybee Posted ADC initialization code. I'm using a debugger to read the result register.

Comment: Check if the ADC peripheral needs to to be calibrated. Have you done all the initialization correctly? Any non linear result may indicate incorrect calibration or some power supply problems. Can you actually read 12V with this ADC on AIN-12V signal? Most ADC peripherals just have 0V to 5V readings.

Comment: Am wondering about supply sequencing...try powering processor first, with reference and ADC input unconnected. Then connect these two inputs, then reboot. You may be experiencing latch-up.

Comment: @AmitM No, this ADC cannot read 12V but I'm using a voltage divider so the maximum voltage it will ever read is 2.2V.

Comment: What is system clock?

Comment: @TimWilliams The main clock, CLK_PER as stated in the data sheet. It's the clock the ADC is seeing. It's running at 24MHz. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 3):

From the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/AVR32DA28-32-48-Data-Sheet-40002228B.pdf), page 577:

[image: ADC conversion timing specifications]

In other words, CLK_ADC from 125kHz to 2MHz.  For 24MHz main clock, a minimum divider of 12 is needed.

Answer (score 1):

After typing my response to Tim about the clock I realized that the ADC clock was running at 12MHz which felt quite fast. After changing the ADC prescaler from 2 (12MHz) to 256 (93.75kHz) the problem went away. Note the main clock (CLK_PER) is running at 24MHz. I cannot give an explanation as to why this fixed the problem but felt like I should post this in case someone else has a similar issue.

[image: ADC Measurements Graph at 93kHz]
[image: Measurements at 12MHz]

Comment: Sometimes missing some details about maximum sampling rate in the manual which said 130 K samples per second can get incorrect result. Nice that you fixed it.  Most low cost MCUs dont have a fast ADC.